# It is possible to check if website use SSG or SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to know if this website: https://www.automobile.it/annunci uses SSG or SSR.
Did this website uses getStaticProps or getServerSideProps?
That is a way to know that?

This website uses Next.js

Comment: It's possible to check that information in the data passed inside `__NEXT_DATA__` script (inspect the page's HTML). At the end of the object passed on that script, you can see the following properties: `"gip":true, "appGip":true`. This indicates the page is SSRd using `getInitialProps`.

Answer (score 1):

Data related to Next js rendering technique is stored inside `<script id="__NEXT_DATA__">` .

I have seen two properties related to `SSG and ISR` technique that are `__N_SSG` and `isFallBack`.

For `SSR` I have'nt seen specific properties but if `__N_SSG` and `isFallBack` were missing , there is a high chance that rendering technique is `SSR`

Also check [This](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15117)  article.